# UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier in watchOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I want to port AWSCore for watchOS and have some problems.
Tell me please,
Does watchOS have an analogy class for UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier in iOS?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WatchKit has [three types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW1) of background tasks: one you can schedule to perform some actions in background, one for url sessions, one that is called to update snapshot.
Additionally, there is opportunity to continue work you've started on foreground for some time (about 25 sec) after app has gone to background. Use ProcessInfo's [performExpiringActivity](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/processinfo/1617030-performexpiringactivity) for that.